# Can C++ code be compiled only for specific CPU architectures. And is there any way to compile it to all architectures

Tags: c++

C++ compiler compiles your code into executable file(.exe) that contains CPU-readable machine code consisting of CPU commands. Different CPUs have different architectures and probably different commands. If CPUs have different commands then executable file compiled for my CPU may not run on another computer with another CPU with another architecture and another commands. For *example* will program compiled on **SkyLake** core run on **KabyLake** core and will program compiled on **Intel CPU** run on **AMD CPU**. Am I right? If so, is there any way to install right executable file with right commands on computer? Please also answer questions in *example*.

Comment: Yes you are right. Compiling on one machine for the architecture of another machine is called *cross compiling*. How you do it depends very much on the particular compiler you are using and the architectures involved. For some combinations it's not going to be possible at all.

Comment: To cross compile for any architecture, you need the *Toolchain* for that architecture installed on your machine. There are various cross compile toolchains put out for different compilers. Since you indicate an `.exe` is an executable rather than an ELF, you would seem to be on windows and looking to compile for something else there? Just about all compilers can compile for various architectures given command line switches, but to also have the result run on the different OS's beyond that requires the toolchain.

Comment: Besides the above comments, is there something specific you want to accomplish, like compiling for two specific platforms?  Or is this just out of curiosity?

Comment: That another computer may require executable file of different format on the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct.  The output of a compiler is machine code, and different CPU architectures have different instruction sets that require different machine code.  So x86 machine code won't run on an ARM-based CPU.

It is possible for a compiler to output machine code for a CPU other than the one the compiler is running on.  This is generally referred to as "cross-compilation", and all of the major C++ compilers have this capability to some extent.

Also note that an executable *file* is just a file that contains machine code.  The operating system's program loader is responsible for loading that machine code from the file into memory and actually beginning execution of it.  For that reason, its entirely possible to have machine code for multiple CPU architectures in one executable file.  The MacOS executable file format, for example, supports this with its "universal binary" format, that lets a single executable file contain machine code for both PowerPC and x86 CPUs.

Different operating systems also use different executable file formats and have different support routines.  That means that a program compiled for Windows won't run on Linux even if they're both running on CPUs with the same architecture.  This is where things like the Windows Subsystem for Linux and WINE come in, allowing one OS to load and execute a program compiled for a different OS.

Answer (score 0):

To compile for "all architectures" is not really possible because some of the are *very* different from what you expect.

The best we can do is to compile to a virtual machine byte code such as Java or .NET. Then the compiled code can run on any system that has the virtual machine installed.

Java is pretty universal so it is a good choice. However, because of its focus on object orientation and garbage collection, it is a little tricky to get C++ compiled for it.

Another virtual machine that is becoming very popular is JavaScript WASM (Web Assembly) This used to be ASM.js but it's now more standardized and cross-browser. It takes advantage of the fact that all current browsers compile JS into machine code, and so WASM is a special form of JS that compiles almost one-to-one into machine code.

See https://medium.com/@tdeniffel/pragmatic-compiling-from-c-to-webassembly-a-guide-a496cc5954b8